# Mediaplayer with two audio tracks

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with mediaplayer.

```
int inlevel=0;
int ingame=1;
MediaPlayer[] music = new MediaPlayer[2];

music[inlevel] = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.jazz);
music[ingame] = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.funky);
music[inlevel].start();
```

When the game begins I call a function for fadeout the music inlevel

```
fadeout();
music[inlevel].pause();
music[ingame].setVolume(volume, volume);
music[ingame].start();**
```

When the game finishs:

```
music[ingame].pause();
music[ingame].seekTo(0);
music[inlevel].start();
```

I don't need the music in level restart from the begin. I need that only for the music ingame.

Everything works good. I have only a problem the second time the game starts. Never happens at the first time.
At the begin of music in game(**), there is a very short piece of the music inlevel. Maybe it is the buffer of Mediaplayer.
I tried with two istance of Mediaplayer, but no sound.
Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: At the begin of music in game(**), try to `music[inlevel].stop()`.

Comment: I don't want to instance inlevel music again, bacause I want it continues in the same point was paused.